# A p-point game with infinitely many ultrafilters

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, ultrafilters, infinite-games

The following game-theoretic characterization of p-points is well known:

> **Theorem A.** An ultrafilter $D$ on the set  $\omega$  of natural numbers is  a p-point if and only if player I does *not* have a winning strategy in the following game $G(D)$ of length $\omega$:
> In the $n$-th move, player I plays a set $A_n \in D$, and player II answers with a natural number $b_n$.  After $\omega$ many rounds, player II wins if the union $\bigcup_n (A_n\cap b_n) $ is in $D$.

(In a more usual formulation, player II has to play a finite subset $w_n \subseteq A_n$, and wins if the union of all the $w_n$ is in $D$; but this version is easily seen to be equivalent to my version.)

A proof sketch: If $D$ is not a p-point, then it is clear how player I wins.  Conversely,  let $\sigma$ be a strategy for player I and assume that $D$ is a p-point. Then there are only countably many sets in $D$ that could be played by I in any $\sigma$-game; let $U\in D$ be a pseudo-intersection of all those sets. Now if $n_0 \ll n_1 \ll \cdots $ increases fast enough [technicalities omitted], and wlog the union $N:=[n_1,n_2)\cup [n_3,n_4) \cup \dots$ is in $D$, then player II can play $n_2,n_4,\dots$ and ensure that the resulting set will be a superset of $U\cap N$.  So $\sigma $ was not a winning strategy.

Now consider the following variant of the game:  Let $D^1,D^2,\dots $ be ultrafilters on $\omega$. In the game $G(D^1,D^2,\ldots)$, player I plays in each move a sequence $(A^1_n,A^2_n,\ldots)$ with $A^i_n\in D^i$ for all $i$, and again player II answers with a number $b_n$.  At the end, player II wins if for all $i$ the set $\bigcup_n (A^i_n\cap b_n) $ is in $D^i$.

(An inessential variant: Require $A^i_n = \omega$ whenever $i\ge n$.)

Using this game, the following generalization of the theorem mentioned above holds:

> **Theorem B.** Player I has no winning strategy in $G(D_1,\ldots)$ iff all $D_i$ are p-points.

The proof is very similar to the one I sketched above, so I suspect that this theorem is well-known.

Does anybody have a reference for Theorem B?